# How to replace "MapPageRoute" in asp.net core 2.2. the method is not found in native

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on migration to asp.net MVC native to Asp.net core 2.2 MVC.

In existing solution using angular js so used **MapPageRoute** to route physical file. how to replace this method in asp.net core2.2.

Used in native mvc: `"routes.MapPageRoute("AdminRoute", "Admin", "~/Views/Index.html");`

please help me out of this issue.

Thanks :)